# Difference between past simple and past perfect here?

Tags: past-tense

> Sergei Nekhamkin, a columnist for the newspaper “Argumenty Nedely”,
> wrote that Grigory Petrov was more popular around St. Petersburg not
> only than Lenin but also than all of Lenin's supporters.

I want to understand which one is right.

1. Sergei Nekhamkin wrote that ...
2. Sergei Nekhamkin has written that ...

According to [Englishpage.com](https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentperfect.html):

- We use the present perfect to say that an action happened at an unspecified time before now.

And the time of "writing" is not important and is not specified.

But I'm confused. Which one do I have to use?

Comment: If it was present perfect it would be 'has written', not 'have wrote'.

Comment: oh thanks @MichaelHarvey

Comment: That *We use the present perfect to say that an action happened **at an unspecified time before now*** is potentially misleading. Simple Past can refer to a past action that happened ***at any time*** in the past - 10 seconds ago, or 10 billion years ago, with no particular implications for how relevant that past action is to the present. But Present Perfect always implies a ***recent*** action (often, continuing right up until time of utterance) that has ***significant relevance to the present time of speaking***.

Comment: Note that it's ***entirely a stylistic choice*** whether to use Simple Past or Present Perfect in your cited context. It doesn't make a lot of sense to me though. Why should Lenin's *supporters* be particularly "popular"? When John Lennon suggested the Beatles were more popular than Christ, would it have made any sense for him to add *...and our **fans** are more popular than Christ too*?

Comment: **Sergei Nekhamkin, a columnist for the newspaper “Argumenty Nedely”, wrote that Grigory Petrov was more popular around St. Petersburg not only than Lenin but also than all of Lenin's supporters. Petrov won the election by a large majority. Lenin, who was in exile at the time, called Grigory Petrov a “demagogue” in an interview to “L'humanite”. This hate continued after the Bolshevik revolution. His writings and books were banned and abandoned to the dusty corners of the archives.**

Are the tense forms in this sentences right? @FumbleFingers

Comment: Yes - all the verb forms in your above comment are correct. But at least *some* of them could in principle be switched to Present Perfect (if you wanted; it doesn't really make much difference in this exact context), as in *His writings and books **have been banned...***

Comment: Thanks a lot. @FumbleFingers

Comment: Actually, I've just realised that Grigory Spiridonovich Petrov *died* almost a century ago. It's probably *not* a good idea to contemplate using Present Perfect in any text about stuff that happened so long ago (and probably isn't particularly relevant to *now*, unless you're a historian! :)

Comment: As he is dead, he wrote, for pete's sake.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, we use present perfect to describe a *present situation* in terms of some past event. So using present perfect here means you're actually talking about something in the present.

In this case, since all those people are dead, including the author, I can't see what present situation it could refer to, so simple past is the only way to go.